# Add allocated buffer to NSMutableDictionay

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to add a dynamically allocated buffer using malloc to a NSMutableDictionary and then free it after the add directly. Is this correct?

Comment: There is a "wrapper" class defined in Objective-C that can be used for this sort of thing.  Unfortunately, I never can remember its name, and Apple's reference site is off-line.

Comment: Probably NSValue, but it doesn't handle free.
OP wanted to do free immediately, presumably to keep the memory management clean, which is a laudable goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is very, very bad.  As soon as you call free, the OS can re-use the memory, so any use of the buffer is bad.

If you want to put data in a mutable dictionary, use NSData instead.

If for some reason you need to store a malloc'd buffer ( e.g. you got it from a library), you'll need to wrap it in an object class.

You can then call free from the wrapper object's dealloc, so free won't be called until the wrapper object is released ( which will be handled by ARC once the dictionary is released.

```
@interface MallocedMemoryWrapper

@property ( nonatomic, assign) void* wrappedMemory;
@end

@implementation MallocedMemoryWrapper
- (MallocedMemoryWrapper*) initWithMemory:(void*) memory {

    self.wrappedMemory = memory;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    free( self.memory);
}
@end

}
```